# Tomcat 8.15 APR Poller failed with error 610,038

Tags: tomcat, http, high-load

I was testing my server with JMeter but when I reach an Highload the server tends to have this error logged on the console and it keeps a lot of active threads on apparent deadlock :

> 30-Jan-2015 17:24:38.504 SEVERE [http-apr-80-Poller] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller.run Poller failed with error [610,038] : [APR does not understand this error code]

Any ideas on what could be the cause?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might have a limit for the connections in server.xml - max connections or maybe a filter defined for that in the application? If you can not find something just get a simple web application and try to see if Tomcat behaves in the same way.Add more MaxTreads in the server.xml, see if the server reaches the RAM/ CPU limit.

Comment: maxThreads was left at default value, so 200. but even with 200 threads I capped the CPU with 800 req/sec, i'll try to increase the max threads, anywawy and see what changes.